# accessing web.config from external project

Tags: asp.net, iis

Project A references Project B which contains IIS Web Application.  If possible - coding c# in Project A, how do I access a Connection String within the web.config of Project B?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why is Project A referencing a Web Application? Typically it's the other way around. Perhaps there is a much simpler way to achieve what you actually want

Comment: I am removing the 45 references to a single SQL server to a single reference originally defined in the web.config.   i suppose I could put this reference in the Project A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. It's only the config file of the current project that is reachable.

A workaround is to put the connection string section in an own config file and use the `connectionSource` attribute to reference that file from both Project A and Project B:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config" />
```